# deployed mern heroku app not hitting endpoint

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

I deployed my MERN app on heroku. However, I am only able to hit the login endpoint, the other api ednpoints are not working. I have tried changing the proxy address from my local server   "http://127.0.0.1:1000" to my heroku's "https://carer-visit.herokuapp.com/". But they are not responding.

Here is the LOGIN endpoint that is working when deployed

```
export function login(userdata) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      
      const loggedInUser = await axios.post(`/api/v1/carers/login`, userdata);

      let { data } = loggedInUser;

      localStorage.setItem('Authtoken', data.token);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(data.user));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
      localStorage.removeItem('Authtoken');
      dispatch(setCurrentUserFailure());
    }
  };
}
```

HERE is an example of another endpoint that is not working when deployed

```
export function fetchCarers() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getCarers());

    try {
      const carerData = await axios.get('/api/v1/carers');

      let {
        data: {
          data: { users },
        },
      } = carerData;

      dispatch(setCarer(users));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(getCarerFailure());
    }
  };
}
```

The problem was from here.

```
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    
      app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        let filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html');
    
        res.sendFile(filePath);
      });
    }
```

I removed the '*' and changed it to this '/'. It started working

```
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
          app.use(express.static('client/build'));
        
          app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            let filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html');
        
            res.sendFile(filePath);
          });
        }
```

Comment: Open dev tools and see the network tab

Comment: Hi @Konrad, sorry for the late response, after checking the response in the headers of the network tab, I realised that same endpoint in my local server returns the data while after deploying to heroku, it returns html skeleton structure which says "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app". What could be the cause? Thanks for your response

Comment: How do you deploy both react and node?

Comment: Hi @Konrad, i have been able to figure it out, the problem was in the routing of my APIs.. I changed  the '*' to ''/'.  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html');

    res.sendFile(filePath);
  });
}   TO

Comment: So I guess that it didn't work locally either